# Magento 2 Admin controller is not working 404 error

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-controller

I don't why my admin controller is not working, I have checked it and everything seems to be ok.

This is my code:

etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="testpakke" frontName="testpakke">
            <module name="Company_Pakke" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Controller/Adminhtml/Download/PDF.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Pakke\Controller\Adminhtml\Download;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class PDF extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }

}
```

when I type http://store/admin_1evvgb/testpakke/download or http://store/admin_1evvgb/testpakke/download/pdf or http://store/admin_1evvgb/testpakke/Adminhtml/download/pdf I get always the 404 error Page not found. Am I typing the path correctly?

Greetings!

Comment: Please share your `menu.xml` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is naming convention issue. Please rename your controller action PDF to Pdf and run setup:upgrade and di : compile. And check route http://store/admin_1evvgb/testpakke/download/pdf

Hope it will help you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I implemented `HttpGetActionInterface` for Controller, but my request type was "Post".
After changing the implementation to `HttpPostActionInterface` it worked.